# Failed to verify bitcode (unrecognized arguments: -disable-llvm-passes)

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ios11, xcode9-beta

Apparently TestFlight now accepts Xcode 9 builds, so I tried to upload a new version of my app for people with iOS 11 beta to test.

The app was uploaded correctly, but then I got an email saying this:

> While processing your iOS app [...] errors occurred in the app
>   thinning process, and your app couldn’t be thinned. [...] For information that may help
>   resolve this issue, see [Tech Note 2432](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2432/_index.html).

I checked the link and it says to export the app for ad hoc deployment in order to reproduce the error. So I did that and this is what I got:

> Failed to verify bitcode in Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib:
>
> error: Clang option verification failed for bitcode 02 (unrecognized
>   arguments: -disable-llvm-passes)

In the logs that error appears again for each framework my app uses. E.g.:

```
code = 0;
description = "Failed to verify bitcode in Realm.framework/Realm:\nerror: Clang option verification failed for bitcode 001 (unrecognized arguments: -disable-llvm-passes)\n\n";
info =             {
};
level = ERROR;
type = "malformed-payload";
```

The same goes for many default libraries, like `libswiftFoundation.dylib`, `libswiftUIKit.dylib` and so on.

So what do I do now?

PS: I don't want to disable bitcode.

---

Edit: I also tried archiving with Xcode 9 and exporting with Xcode 8. I get the same errors.

Comment: Which build of `Xcode 9` are you using, and can you check that you have the file `Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/bitcode_build_tool/verifier.py` present?

Comment: @l'L'l Build `9M137d`. And yes, `verifier.py` is there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but I was curious if [`commenting out line line 61`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9690d4d6fc82a1434e03682dacf4f4f2#file-verifier-py-L61) might have any effect on the end result, and then you re-submitted your app. The problem could likely be on the Apple end of things too, so it might be a waste of time. The `verifier.py` is a new addition to Xcode 9, as they've changed up the way the build system works. It seems the python script is a 'hack' of sorts in order to pass the flags properly to the compiler.

Comment: @l'L'l It didn't work. :/ I guess it must really be on Apple's side. I just wonder why it's happening to me and not to other people, but oh, well… hopefully the next version of Xcode fixes it.

Comment: One final suggestion I might have would be to try using Application Loader if you haven't already; sometimes that works better than the archive method.

Comment: @l'L'l Yeah, I've tried that already, no luck. :/ Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @dbmrq Hi ! Did you find a solution ? Did you have in your settings the `-disable-llvm-passes` ? If so, did you try to remove it ?

Comment: @zarghol The problem just disappeared with a new TestFlight release. I think it was a problem with the beta back then. ‍♂️

Comment: @dbmrq ok... too bad, I have a similar issue, with -Osize